# Why does this C# assignment throw an exception?

Tags: c#

```
public class A
{
    private string _a_string;
    public string AString
    {
        get { return _a_string; }
        set {  _a_string = value; }
    }
}

public class B
{
    private string _b_string;
    private A _a;

    public A A
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set { _a = value; }
    }

    public string BString
    {
        get { return _b_string;  }
        set { _b_string = value; }
    }
}
```

This does not work:

```
    B _b = new B { A = { AString = "aString" }, BString = "bString" };
```

**System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

This works:

```
    B _b = new B { A = new A { AString = "aString" }, BString = "bString" };
```

Both compile fine in VS2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no instantiation of A within B unless you explicitly instantiate it as in your second example.

Change to;

```
public class B
{
    private string _b_string;
    private A _a = new A();

    public A A
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set { _a = value; }
    }

    public string BString
    {
        get { return _b_string;  }
        set { _b_string = value; }
    }
}
```

To use the first example.

In short, without the **new A()**, there is no **A** which is the cause of the NullReferenceException

Comment: Thanks - I know how to get it to work now, but I really thought  A = { AString = "aString" } was assignment enough.

Answer (score 6):

The line

```
B _b = new B { A = { AString = "aString" }, BString = "bString" };
```

is equivalent to

```
B _b = new B();
_b.A.AString = "aString"; // null reference here: _b.A == null
_b.BString = "bString";
```

I think in this form it's clear what's happening.

Compare this with the equivalent form of the expression that works:

```
B _b = new B();
_b.A = new A();
_b.A.AString = "aString"; // just fine now
_b.BString = "bString";
```

Comment: You are probably correct, but I thought  A = { AString = "aString" } would take care of creating an instance of A on its own. I guess I will have to look at the IL to really find out...

Comment: @OtávioDécio: It does not, because the compiler simply transforms the "shorthand" syntax to the long one. But to tell you the truth, if you had asked me an hour ago I wouldn't have recognized the problematic expression as legal C#.

Comment: although I fixed my code I think this behavior is dangerous enough to cause some confusion. Guess I will have to be more orthodox when initializing objects from now on.

Comment: @OtávioDécio: I think it's by far preferable to initialize the field backing `B.A` inside `class B`, if it does not violate the semantics of the class. This way you won't have to worry about you (or anyone else) falling into this trap.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the code is effectively transformed by the compiler into

```
B b = new B();
A a = b.A;
a.AString = "aString";
b.BString = "bString";
```

Since you never assigned `b.A` to an instance, you get the exception (specifically, since you never assigned `b.A`, `a` is null and thus `a.AString` is going to throw a `NullReferenceException`). **The fact that nowhere is there code of the form `new A...` is a huge clue that an instance of `A` is never created.**

You could solve this problem by adding `A = new A()` to the constructor of `B`, or adding a field initializer to `B._a`.

In the second case, the code is transformed by the compiler into

```
B b = new B();
A a = new A();
a.AString = "aString";    
b.A = a;
b.BString = "bString";
```

This is okay, because now we have an instance of `A`.

Comment: Thank you - but why is the compiler not creating a new instance of A when I write  A = { AString = "aString" } ?

Comment: Because you didn't use `new A` anywhere. It's not going to create an instance unless you tell it to. You tell it to by using the `new` keyword.

Comment: Because there is no explicit instantiation of A within your class or code. At the point you are writing A = { AString = "aString" }, it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use

```
A = { AString = "aString" }
```

because of the same reason you did

```
B _b = new B {
```

you must declare an instance of B(and A) in order to use it.

If you would have written

```
B = B{...
```

you would get a similar error

Comment: @Reed - If I can't it is fine, but if so - why is the compiler taking it?

Comment: Because at compile time you are not yet attempting to access A, so it will compile. The compiler knows A is a valid class, but it is unable to determine at that point whether it has been instantiated or not, as this could happen in other places.

Comment: @Chris - you are correct, but I feel like this is an easy trap to fall into.

Comment: Agreed, but you live and learn and I am sure you will spot problems like this a lot easier now you know why :)

Comment: @Reed = btw writing B = B { ... as in your last line is not allowed by the compiler.